# working with multiple elements within a selector result

Tags: jquery-selectors

Why some jquery operations work with all elements within a selector result and others work only with the first element in the match?

For example `$(".selector").click` function assigns an event to all elements within a selector result, but `$('.selector]').offset().top` returns the value only of the first element in the result set.

How can I know what is the behavior for each operation?

Answer (score 0):

Some jquery functions can accept the multiple dom elements while the others can work with single one only. `$(".selector")` is an object, when you call some function for it the all elements from the object or only the first one will be passed to the function.

`offset()` function description:

> Get the current coordinates **of the first element**, or set the
>   coordinates **of every element**, in the set of matched elements, relative
>   to the document.

So if you call `offset()` without parameters it will return position of the first element; `offset({ top: y, left: x })` will set the same `top` and `left` properties for the all elements of the jquery object.

To see how a function works read its documentation.

Comment: thank you, so every time I have to check if the result is single or multiple elements and if it has multiple elements I have to iterate.

Comment: that's not a good practice to check whether it's a single or multiple elements. When you call any function you have to know what it could return.